# Request for creation of performance site under Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, feature-request, site-proposal

I request for creation of performance category under stackexchange.com, just like  [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or  [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) , etc. I think performance in a IT field is as important as any of the other fields in IT. I can't stress more the importance of performance  than like below.

If the software/hardware performance badly but works then it is no more useful than a non working code. The user would be pissed off and would never use it again or more serious he could claim for a refund (which is perfectly normal). Performance is especially important in field of product development.

More so in the world of today's online services, like social networking, photo sharing, video streaming, etc. which are all resource intensive and hence performance team has a big role to play here. But my Google search on performance on Stack Exchange returned nothing like a dedicated site for it. So I think it is high time we raise a dedicated site for this. Performance is important in any field, so I wonder why Stack Exchange people have not considered it seriously? Please prove me wrong.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: By the way, welcome to Meta Stack Overflow! Here downvotes mean something different than they do on the main site, namely that people *disagree* with your proposed feature request. They don't mean that you asked a terrible, horrible, awful question and deserve to be punished or anything like that.

Comment: @cody *except when it does*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is absolutely no point in having or creating a dedicated site for performance-related questions.

As you say:

> Performance is important in any field

**That's precisely *why* we haven't created a dedicated site for it!** The thing about performance issues is that they always fall neatly into their larger, encompassing category. Whatever field you're working in when you're trying to optimize performance is the site that your questions belong on.

Most of the time, this category of questions will probably be programming-related and thus would belong on [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/). But you might also be trying to optimize the performance of your desktop computer, and questions about that would belong on [Super User](http://www.superuser.com/). Questions about optimizing the throughput of your servers would belong on [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com/). Questions about mathematical optimization would belong on [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com). *Et cetera*.

The primary reason for this is because **there is no such thing as a "performance expert"**. Experts in the field of performance enhancements will always and necessarily be experts in the field of whatever object whose performance you are trying to enhance. Therefore, a dedicated "performance" site would never work, because there'd be no one qualified to answer the questions. There's no foreseeable target audience. Just because something is cool & hip doesn't mean it's a good candidate for a Q&A site.

Comment: Thanks Cody Gray. Now i understand that sys admin alone cannot do performance measurement. It is difficult topic to zero in. I received a lot of bad ratings and i felt bad and thanks cody gray for clearing the air regarding bad rating and i am now peaceful. Cody gray you rock. So there is no definitive answer for performance, it is more relative term on which you base your measurement. It requires a team of experts to zero in on performance. The team experts is all who are even loosely associated with the product. Difficult subject hoo.

Comment: @ashwin also, the "performance" people would have nothing in common and no reason to care about the topic because it's so general...